# Python function optional arguments - possible to add as condition?

Tags: python, function, arguments, conditional-statements, optional-parameters

Is it possible, somehow, to aassign a condtional statement toan optional argument?

My initial attempts, using the following construct, have been unsuccessful:

```
y = {some value} if x == {someValue} else {anotherValue}
```

where x has assigned beforehand.

More specifically, I want my function signature to look something like:

```
def x(a, b = 'a' if someModule.someFunction() else someModule.someOtherFunction()):
   :
   :
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, that's exactly how you do it. You may want to keep in mind that `b`'s default value will be set immediately after you define the function, which may not be desirable:

```
def test():
    print("I'm called only once")
    return False

def foo(b=5 if test() else 10):
    print(b)

foo()
foo()
```

And the output:

```
I'm called only once
10
10
```

Just because this is possible doesn't mean that you should do it. I wouldn't, at least. The verbose way with using `None` as a placeholder is easier to understand:

```
def foo(b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = 5 if test() else 10

    print b
```